# Windows 10 IOT core, Raspberry pi 2, Fails to connect: Objectnotfound measure-object:string

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Moved this question to [RaspberryPi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33832/windows-10-iot-core-fails-to-connect-using-powershell-objectnotfound-measure-o)

Comment: This might be a better fit for the [Raspberry PI SE](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Did you add a PowerShell profile script to the Windows 10 IoT image by any chance? It acts like it is trying to run a missing command while the session is starting up.

Comment: @KeithHill, No I did not add any additional powershell profile scripts to the image. For installation I followed these steps: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupPCRPI.htm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker has already moved it to a different site in the network.